# Command to show Plank dock

Tags: release-loki, plank, keyboard-shortcuts, command-line

I want to keep the dock hidden and to show it with a short-key associated to a command.

Is there a such command to show the Plank dock?

When shown I would prefer to have it under rather than above maximized window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dock becomes visible when no window pressures it.

**Super-Tab**

The dock is always shown on an empty workspace. So, the shortkey to cycle workspaces Super-Tab can be used. 'Restrict to workspace' should better not be enabled in this case. Cycling to an empty workspace with Super-Tab reveals the hidden dock.

**Super-UpArrow**

Toggling Maximize on/off may show the hidden dock.